# Debugging Nuget Packages that live in Artifactory

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity, artifactory

I have a class library that is built and deployed to JFrog Artifactory via Team City that is shared in a few web applications I have.  The question I have is what is the best approach to be able to debug and step into the class library code that is being referenced in the manage nuget package?  I have the store setup as a source to artifactory where I add and update any changes to the packages etc. it is internal of course.  The goal I am looking for is to be able to step into the methods being called when using the referenced library within my code.   I was thinking maybe Team City because that is not Production based per say as Artifactory is but I would then have to probably make changes etc.

I know Artifactory and Team City both can be setup as a symbol server to store PDB files so is the correct approach to get this to step into the code make Artifactory the symbol server and then in Visual Studio setup the remote symbol server would that allow the package referenced to step into?

Thanks all for any information trying to wrap my head around best approach.  I don't want to always remove the nuget reference and bring the class library source code down and add to my solution to debug all the time.

Comment: When you add the following lines in your csproj-file for your class library `<IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>` and `<SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>` there should be a `snupkg` in your bin/Release folder after running `nuget pack`. These are the symbols for your package. If you then publish your `nupkg` and your `snupkg` to JFrog, and enable `source code stepping`, you should be able to debug your code for your package

Comment: I don't know if JFrog supports uploading `snupkg` but there may be additional configuration required: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Microsoft+Symbol+Server

Comment: source code stepping is that a setting or in Visual Studio I need to point to a remove symbol server?

Comment: I'm sorry. In fact you have to disable `Enable Just My Code`. You can find this option in `Visual Studio → Debug → Options → Enable Just My Code`. If the debugger is able to find the symbols for your package then you should be able to step into the source code.